# Mass Transit unable to deserialize collections with exactly one element

Tags: c#, json.net, masstransit

I've got a Mass Transit message interface like this:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    ICollection<PersonalName> Names { get; }
}

public class PersonalName
{
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Use { get; set; }
}
```

And this works for serializing and deserializing the message using the `JsonMessageSerializer`. I can also serialize the message using the `XmlMessageSerializer`, and the result looks a bit like this:

```xml
<person>
    <names>
        <familyName>Simpson</familyName>
        <givenName>Homer</givenName>
        <secondName>Jay</secondName>
        <use>Official</use>
    </names>
    <names>
        <givenName>Homie</givenName>
        <use>Nickname</use>
    </names>
</person>
```

And I can deserialize just it if the collection is empty or if it has more than one element. However, if the collection contains **exactly one** element, when I go to deserialize it, I get this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) into type '`` System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[MyNs.PersonalName] ``' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'person.names.familyName'.

I can fix this by using an array or `List<T>`, but I'd really like to avoid doing that. Is there a way to get Mass Transit's `XmlMessageSerializer` to deserialize `ICollection<T>` types? Since Mass Transit uses Json.NET for serialization under the hood (even for XML), I'm hoping there's some way of annotating the type so that it can accept an `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Is an `IList<T>` acceptable instead of `ICollection<T>`? If not, open up an issue on the GitHub (https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit) and maybe we can make that work.

Comment: And since `ICollection<T>` is implemented by `IList<T>`, it's likely just binding the right serializer to `ICollection<T>`, so likely an easy fix.

Comment: @Travis I'm developing a message library where I'd like to semantically identify this collection as a 'bag', where order or uniqueness is not important. In other parts of the library, where order is important, I use `IList`, and where uniqueness is important I use `ISet`. So I can use an `IList`, but it would mean adopting the semantics inherent in a `IList` where it's not appropriate. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to deserialize:

```
{"FamilyName":"Smith","GivenName":"John"}
```

you have to pass in an array to deserialize:

```
[{"FamilyName":"Smith","GivenName":"John"}]
```

Comment: Mass Transit uses Json.NET to do XML serialization, see my update for an example.